# Error While Creating a Dialog Box Using XML Fragments

Tags: sapui5

I am getting the below error while trying to display a dialog box after user presses a button,

> sap-ui-core.js:80 Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/m/buttons.js' from resources/sap/m/buttons.js: 404 - Resource could not be found!

Please find the XML code below.

```
<Dialog xmlns="sap.m"
  icon="sap.icon://filter"
  title="Filter product details">
  <content>
    <List id="ls2"
      items="{/value}"
      mode="MultiSelect">
      <StandardListItem title="{CompanyName}"/>
    </List>
  </content>
  <buttons>
    <Button text="ok" icon="sap-icon://accept" press="handleok"/>
    <Button text="Cancel" icon="sap.icon://cancel"/>  
  </buttons>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: What's the UI5 version you're using (`sap.ui.version`)?

Comment: Hi..i have the latest version

Comment: So, what do you get when you enter `sap.ui.version` in runtime on your browser console? The fact that the same code works fine with `<end/beginButton>` indicates that the current version is below 1.21.1 since Dialog didn't have the `buttons` aggregation until then. The only mistake I can see right now are the invalid icon paths: Instead of `icon="sap.icon://...`, it should be `icon="sap-icon://...`. But that's not the main issue here. Do you use somewhere else `buttons` in your application?

Comment: Must be the case! coz my version is 1.20.7.let me install the latest version and run the application. many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that the UI5 version was quite outdated after all. The aggregation [`buttons` was introduced as of version 1.21.1](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/be43426cd97e3fa6bb00bffc667cda4edd36cef0/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Dialog.js#L241-L245).

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the `sap.m.Dialog` control inside a FragmentDefinition according to the [walkthrough guide](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.16/code/webapp%252Fview%252FHelloDialog.fragment.xml).

Here is minimal example https://embed.plnkr.co/OjUCXTg2afohZyDvPp67/

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Dialog
        id="helloDialog"
        title="Hello World">
      <buttons>
        <Button text="Ok">
        <Button text="Cancel">
      </buttons>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

And instead of using a dialog control you can use a [sap.m.MessageBox](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.MessageBox/preview) control which provides you with "Ok" and "Cancel" or custom buttons.

Comment: If the dialog is the only element in the XML file, it doesn't have to be wrapped around by `<core:FragmentDefinition ...`. The FragmentDefinition is only needed when there are multiple root nodes since [XML documents need to have a single root node](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/23b9c779c2274213a281c1fc46b4962b).