# Display Only Selected Rows in sap.m.Table

Tags: sapui5

I have a table created by using sap.m.Table and a filter in the `headerToolbar`.

1. When the user clicks on the filter button, a list, which contains the key field of the table, should display with all available rows.
2. When the user selects and clicks on <kbd>OK</kbd> in the dialog, only
   those rows should be displayed in the table.

The Dialog has list of values along with <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>CANCEL</kbd> buttons.

I am trying to achieve it by changing the model of the table after user selection but could not get it. Can someone please let me know where I went wrong and if any other better way to do it?

```
var list = new sap.ui.getCore().byId("ls2");
var sel = list.getSelectedItems();
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(oModel);
var oElement = sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("table1");
oElement.setModel(oModel);`
```

[image: Display Table]

[image: click on filter,then select values from the list and click "Ok"]

After <kbd>OK</kbd>, the table should display values which are selected from the list.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I'm getting the last sentences of the first paragraph. Could you attach some mockups /screenshots of what you're trying to do and *why*? Is the table empty initially?

Comment: not sure if I understood the problem, are you trying to filter some criteria in a dialog which affect the Table?

Comment: Don't filter the items at the model level. Instead, get the item binding and apply a filter to the binding.

Comment: let me try this option too...BTW just for clarification, shouldn't we use filter at model level ? if yes, why? If no, why my code is not working did i do something wrong :(  please put me on the right track....if my approach is wrong....Many thanks!

Comment: @Renukaswathi Thanks for the update. But I still don't understand the use case of this. What's the benefit of displaying only selected rows? Technically, that's surely feasible but I don't see any point of doing it.. Is it for exercise?

Comment: @Renukaswathi Btw. did you upgrade UI5 resources by now or are you [still on 1.20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839161/error-while-creating-a-dialog-box-using-xml-fragments#comment84747051_48839161)?

Comment: yes @boghyon As i am in learning stage of SAP UI5 ,doing it for exercise. I am trying to apply the filter concept here.but not clearly getting how would i get the selected key values from the list ,could you please help me getting  how to get the values from the list and pass it to the filter,conceptually....  I am on the latest version,1.50.8 now! :)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to set the columns that are shown by the Table, but instead you are changing the filters you want to manage, or even the oData model that feeds the table. That's wrong.

Use the property useTablePersonalisation="true" in your table.

It will appear a "control" button above your table. Click it and go to the tab "Columns" (it should be default). Then choose the columns you want to be displayed.

Tell me if it is enough for you.

Comment: I don't think he's trying to display certain columns. Also `useTablePersonalisation` is available only for [SmartTable](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable) which is based on sap.ui.table.Table. The question author is using sap.m.Table.